# Python: idiomatic way to drop items from a list until an item matches a condition?

Tags: python

I just wrote this little helper, but I have a strong feeling such a thing "should already exist". What is it called?

```
@listify
def drop_up_to_and_including(l, f):
    """Drops items from a list 'l' up until and including an element `e` is found for which `f(e) == True`

    Example::
    >>> drop_up_to_and_including(range(10), lambda x: x == 5)
    [6, 7, 8, 9]
    """
    found = False
    for e in l:
        if found:
            yield e

        if f(e):
            # note: after yield-statement; so we'll yield starting from the first item _after_ f(e) == True
            found = True
```

`listify` does what you think it does: https://github.com/shazow/unstdlib.py/blob/master/unstdlib/standard/list_.py#L149

Comment: [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

Comment: @user3100115: `dropwhile` doesn't drop the first true element, though.

Comment: why? it is just as easy to do a list comp with a conditional to generate a new list containing what you want, why mess with the original?

Comment: @jwodder can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user3100115: The OP's function drops all leading elements for which `f(elem)` is false *and* drops the first element for which `f(elem)` is true.  `dropwhile` only does the first part.

Comment: So, why not dropwhile and dropping the first element after dropwhile if f is true for it?

Edit: Oops. my bad. Didn't read dropwhile "drops while" f is true...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) but need to drop the first matching element
and need to invert the logic:

```
drop_up_to_and_including = lambda l,f : list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda y: not(f(y)),l))[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from the comments:

```
>>> drop_up_to_and_including = lambda f, l: list(dropwhile(f, l))[1:]
>>> drop_up_to_and_including(lambda x: x != 5, range(10))
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Swaps the parameters w.r.t. the question to "stay close to the idiomatic way" and enable currying.